# How can an object affect another object from the same class?

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

I'm  new in python and aims to master OO in python. Here I try to draw, as a. example, a rectangle on a canvas placed in a frame trough a button from another frame which is defined through the same class. More generally said: How can an objects communicate to each other? The current code results in an error: AttributeError: 'Windows' object has no attribute 'canvas_1'

```
import tkinter as tk
class Windows():
    def __init__(self, master, width, height, colour, row, column, cell_size):
        self.frame_1 = tk.Frame(master, width=width+20, height=height+20, bg='white')
        self.frame_1.grid(row=row, column=column)
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.row=row
        self.column=column
        self.colour=colour

    def make_canvas(self):
        self.canvas_1 = tk.Canvas(self.frame_1, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg=self.colour,
                               borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas_1.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.canvas_1.create_rectangle(0,0,self.width-1, self.height-1)

    def draw_rectangle(self):
        self.canvas_1.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100)

    def make_button(self, text, row, column):
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame_1, text=text,command=self.draw_rectangle)
        self.button.grid(row=row, column=column)

master = tk.Tk()
window_1 = Windows(master, width=600, height=400, colour='yellow', row=1, column=0, cell_size=10 )
window_1.make_canvas()
window_2 = Windows(master, width=600, height=100, colour='white', row=3, column=0,   cell_size=10)
window_2.make_button('button_1',0,0)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: In you `__init__` constructor, try `self.canvas_1 = None`

Comment: window_2 instance doesn't have canvas_1 defined because you didn't call `make_canvas`. But the button callback relies on `canvas_1` to exist. You have 2 different instances here

Comment: @JacobIRR this is probably going to fail as canvas_1 needs to be valid

Comment: Thank you so much for your rapid answers. Yes it is true that windows-2 doesn't have a canvas. What I'm trying to do is affecting what happens in window-1 through a button in windows_2. Both windows are an instance of the same class. So how can objects affect each other?

Comment: Unfortunately, self.canvas_1=None  did not work. I applied it by accident in another code. Only, if I make one instance of the window, thus window_1, and define another frame in the same init method I get button that works. So how objects can communicate is stil not clear for me. Thanks nevertheless for your suggestions so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can an objects communicate to each other?

The rule is pretty simple: to interact with another object you need a reference to the other object. Through that reference, they can call any method or access any public attribute. In your case, if you want `window_2` to be able to control `window_1`, you need to pass `window_1` into `window_2`.

There are many ways to do this. The correct way depends on what you're wanting to accomplish. For example, do you need two-way communication? Will you have multiple windows controlling a single window? Or, will a single window need to control multiple other windows? Or do multiple windows need to control multiple windows? Do you want to specify the window on every function call, or set a default window? In every one of those cases, the root of the solution is the same: a window needs to have a reference to another window.

In your specific example, one solution is to tell `make_button` which window to draw in by passing in an optional `window` parameter. It will in the requested window if defined, or in its own window if not defined.

Here's an example:

```
def make_button(self, text, row, column, other_window=None):
    window = self if other_window is None else other_window
    self.button = tk.Button(self.frame_1, text=text,command=window.draw_rectangle)
    self.button.grid(row=row, column=column)
...
window_2.make_button('Draw in window 1',0,0, other_window=window_1)
```

Comment: Brian Oakley, thank you so much. Now, more general because I would like to model the interaction between biological) genes, is this in principle how instances from classes communicate? Thus if I define e.g. a gene class and derive multiple instances of that class (particular genes) I should refer on a similar way their mutual interactions?

Comment: @Sjaak: yes, this example is in principle how instances communicate - they get a reference to some other object and through that they can pass information. They either need to be given a reference, or be given a way to get a reference.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is what most OO languages refer to as static variables. A variable accessible from a class that's identicle in each class instance. Python offers several options, but the simplest way would probably be to remove the `self.` from any refetences to `canvas`. You would also need to ensure `make_canvas` is called exactly once before anything else.